# Create field in kibana at run time

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

We have a web service application that exposes certain webservices over http. The webservice requests are xml messages sent in a SOAP envelope. The application logs the request and response messages for audit purposes.Since the application processes multiple webservices, the xml messages are different.

I am trying to use the ELK stack for log analysis. I have used logstash to parse the log file and have put the xml message into an elasticsearch field.

Is there a way in Kibana using which the user can extract a certain tag from the xml message field, assign it to a different field and create graphs out of it? I do not want to do this in logstash, but would like to do it in Kibana at run time.

Comment: This is what logstash is for (the xml filter specifically).  Can you explain why you don't want to use logstash, considering that you're already using it?

Comment: I'd like the end users to have the flexibility to determine which xml tag to filter on. I cant do this if I use logstash as I wont know which fields the users may be interested in while I am indexing the log file. I did look at scripted fields but I am not able to parse xml using them.

Comment: Logstash has an xml{} filter that will make fields for whatever structure it finds in your xml.  This will allow your users to search on anything in the xml.